# How can I add an owner to an Azure app account that has no owners?

Tags: azure

We have an Azure app account that had an owner who departed the company. Subsequently the app is now locked due to the owners account being deleted. We need to add a new owner to the account so that we can continue to update it e.g. add client ids etc. How can we do this?

Comment: What do you mean by app account? Do you mean a specific Azure AD application, or access to the whole of your Azure subscription/tenant?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have now got an answer for this from MS tech support.

Comment: It would be good if you would post the resolution as an answer so it can help others.

Comment: Unfortunately MS Tech support did not provide any details.